# Whats wrong in this python mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing a script which requires to insert value in db

I have written a query like

```
cur.execute('''INSERT into agent_info set (didNo,agentNumber,agentOrder,agentName,agentId,agentEmail,dateOfCreation,agentStatus,) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ''',(row[0],row[2],'1','SomeName',id_generator(),'hey',ti,'FREE'))
```

But I am getting an error near to `agentStatus`

Here is the error:

```
ProgrammingError(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(didNo,agentNumber,agentOrder,agentName,agentId,agentEmail,dateOfCreation,agentS' at line 1")
```

Comment: Remove set in insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma too many and need to *remove* the `set` :

```sql
INSERT into agent_info set
--                     ^^^
(didNo,agentNumber,agentOrder,agentName,agentId,
 agentEmail,dateOfCreation,agentStatus,)
--                          ----------^
values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

Corrected statement:

```
INSERT into agent_info
(didNo,agentNumber,agentOrder,agentName,agentId,
 agentEmail,dateOfCreation,agentStatus)
values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

The `SET` should only be used in the MySQL `INSERT INTO <table> SET col1=val1, col2=val2` non-standard SQL extension.

Comment: I am getting the same error initially there were no comma \